# redmine wk_time (time & expense) plugin over https? / javascript http content blocked

Tags: plugins, https, redmine

I've got:
Redmine v: 2.3.1.stable
Plugin redmine_wktime v: 1.5

When accessing wktime plugin javascript gives error:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://my.redmine.site/issues/5' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://my.redmine.site/wktime/getStatus?startDate=2014-10-30': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

The question is how can I configure wk_time plugin to load over https as well?
There are some configs in routes.rb file, like:

```
get 'wktime/getStatus', :to => 'wktime#getStatus'
```

But how can I set (rake?) it to load wk_time plugin over https? Don't know if routes.rb file is the right place to do it.

Similar question has been asked by someone at redmine.org, but still without answear (http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/41459)

Any suggestion very appreciated.
Kind regards!

Comment: exactly going through the same situation. were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I've got no solution so far. At redmine.org still no suggestions. I'll try to find and fix it (I hope..) in plugin code (there must be a definition to load wk_time plugin through http so let's make it use https instead ;) Don't know if it's a right way to resolve the problem, but I'll try. I'll share the solution if I find one.

Comment: What I have noticed so far is, redmine doesn't use the protocol we define in config/settings.yml. It's really hard to find route mappings since i'm new to both redmine and ruby. I'm also trying to figure out a solution. Will share it if i get one :)

Comment: "protocol: default: https" in settings.yml file is only used by redmine to generate links in emails, so we need to find somewhere else ;)

Comment: Found something, check below :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL for the `wktime/getStatus` request sets from `showEntryWarning` function in [redmine]\plugins\remine_wktime\assets\javascripts\wkstatus.js

It derives the URL from below mentioned section in redmine_wktime plugin's init.rb file.

```
def showWarningMsg(req)     
    wktime_helper = Object.new.extend(WktimeHelper)     
    host_with_subdir = wktime_helper.getHostAndDir(req)             
    "<div id='divError'><font color='red'>#{l(:label_warning_wktime_time_entry)}</font> 
        <input type='hidden' id='getstatus_url' value='#{url_for(:controller => 'wktime', :action => 'getStatus',:host => host_with_subdir)}'>  
    </div>"     
end
```

so as you can see it calls a method named `url_for()` in here. This method returns the generated URL. This url_for() method is located in a gem called `actionpack`. Actually the url_for() method returns the URL for a set of options provided. If we specify the "host" in options passing to url_for() it doesn't return the relative path, instead it returns a url with protocol as http. So change the code in init.rb file as below. [remove the `host => host_with_subdir` parameter in url_for() method call].

```
def showWarningMsg(req)     
    wktime_helper = Object.new.extend(WktimeHelper)     
    host_with_subdir = wktime_helper.getHostAndDir(req)             
    "<div id='divError'><font color='red'>#{l(:label_warning_wktime_time_entry)}</font> 
        <input type='hidden' id='getstatus_url' value='#{url_for(:controller => 'wktime', :action => 'getStatus')}'>    
    </div>"     
end
```

Then redmine will get the protocol for the url from request's protocol. And you content will be loading over https :D

Comment: Man you rock! :) That's it. It solved my problem, now the content of wktime plugin loads over https as it should. Very big thank for sharing the solution! :)

Comment: No worries, Happy to share since these are very rare issues :)

Answer (score 0):

this if fixed in Time & Expense 1.8, please see http://www.redmine.org/plugins/wk-time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.